# Optimizing sorting container of objects with heap-allocated buffers - how to avoid hard-copying buffers?

Tags: c++, optimization, sorting

I was making sure I knew how to do the op= and copy constructor correctly in order to `sort()` properly, so I wrote up a test case. After getting it to work, I realized that the op= was hard-copying all the `data_`.

I figure if I wanted to sort a container with this structure (its elements have heap allocated char buffer arrays), it'd be faster to just swap the pointers around. Is there a way to do that? Would I have to write my own sort/swap function?

```
#include    <deque>
//#include  <string>
//#include  <utility>
//#include  <cstdlib>
#include    <cstring>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <fstream>
#include    <algorithm> // I use sort(), so why does this still compile when commented out?

#include    <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include    <boost/foreach.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

class Page
{
    public:
        // constructor
        Page(const char* path, const char* data, int size) :
            path_(fs::path(path)),
            size_(size),
            rawdata_(new char[size])
        {
//          cout    << "Creating Page..." << endl;
            strncpy(rawdata_, data, size);
//          cout    << "done creating Page..." << endl;
        }
        // copy constructor
        Page(const Page& other) :
            path_(fs::path(other.path())),
            size_(other.size()),
            rawdata_(new char[other.size()])
        {
//          cout    << "Copying Page..." << endl;
            strncpy(data_, other.data(), size_);
//          cout    << "done copying Page..." << endl;
        }
        // destructor
        ~Page() { delete[] data_; }
        // accessors
        const fs::path& path() const { return path_; }
        const char* data() const { return rawdata_; }
        int size() const { return size_; }
        // operators
        Page& operator = (const Page& other) {
            if (this == &other)
                return *this;
            char* newImage = new char[other.size()];
            strncpy(newImage, other.data(), other.size());
            delete[] data_;
            rawdata_ = newImage;
            path_ = fs::path(other.path());
            size_ = other.size();
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator < (const Page& other) const { return path_ < other.path();    }
    private:
        fs::path path_;
        int size_;
        char* rawdata_;
};

class Book
{
    public:
        Book(const char* path) :
            path_(fs::path(path))
        {
            cout    << "Creating Book..." << endl;
            cout    << "pushing back #1" << endl;
            // below, the RawData will be coming from methods like
            // fstream.read(char* buffer, int filesize); or
            // unzReadCurrentFile(unzFile zipFile, char* buffer, int size);
            pages_.push_back(Page("image1.jpg", "firstImageRawData", 17));
            cout    << "pushing back #3" << endl;
            pages_.push_back(Page("image3.jpg", "thirdImageRawData", 17));
            cout    << "pushing back #2" << endl;
            pages_.push_back(Page("image2.jpg", "secondImageRawData", 18));

            cout    << "testing operator <" << endl;
            cout    << pages_[0].path().string() << (pages_[0] < pages_[1]? " < " : " > ") << pages_[1].path().string() << endl;
            cout    << pages_[1].path().string() << (pages_[1] < pages_[2]? " < " : " > ") << pages_[2].path().string() << endl;
            cout    << pages_[0].path().string() << (pages_[0] < pages_[2]? " < " : " > ") << pages_[2].path().string() << endl;

            cout    << "sorting" << endl;
            BOOST_FOREACH (Page p, pages_)
                cout    << p.path().string() << endl;
            sort(pages_.begin(), pages_.end());
            cout << "done sorting\n";
            BOOST_FOREACH (Page p, pages_)
                cout    << p.path().string() << endl;

            cout    << "checking datas" << endl;
            BOOST_FOREACH (Page p, pages_) {
                char data[p.size() + 1];
                strncpy((char*)&data, p.data(), p.size());
                data[p.size()] = '\0';
                cout    << p.path().string() << " " << data << endl;
            }
            cout    << "done Creating Book" << endl;
        }

        const Page& getFirstPage() { return pages_[0]; }
    private:
        deque<Page> pages_;
        fs::path path_;
};

int main() {
    Book* book = new Book("/some/path/");
    // below is an example of where the rawdata is used
    // by a method that has a char* parameter
    ofstream outFile("outimage.jpg");
    outFile.write(book->getFirstPage().data(), book->getFirstPage().size());
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: Additionally, you never delete your `book` in main, so all your work is undermined anyway. :)

Comment: The book in main isn't really the focus.

Should I be using std::string for filestreams? They're not supposed to be readable character streams. When I learned to do file i/o it was always with fstream and creating a char buffer. Plus, I'm getting the streams from an unzip and unrar library, which ask for raw char* as well.

Comment: You should never be doing manual memory allocations. If it's for raw data, use `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: That said, you can possibly help out your library's implementation of `sort` by making swap functions. Add a member function `swap` that takes a reference to another instance, and call `std::swap` on each of your members. Then outside and below the class, add a `swap` that takes two references, like: `void swap(T& x, T& y) { x.swap(y); }`. Lastly, you can specialize `swap` in the `std` namespace, which is allowed. `namespace std { template <>void swap(T& x, T& y) { x.swap(y); } }`.

Comment: As far as using vectors go, Won't I need to create an intermediate char array anyway for methods like `fstream.read(char* buffer, int filesize)`? I need to pass the raw data to something else later, which takes `char*`, so why bother using a vector? Also, someone else suggested using `boost::shared_ptr` as an alternative for the custom `swap` (which I don't have experience with).

Comment: You can get the raw vector with `&vec[0]`.

Comment: Thanks! Then this also means having my Page own vectors will allow the deque<Page> to be sorted without needing to deep-copy/swap the vector<char>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use raw char * in this scenario as it's going to be an unnecessary headache. Use `std::string` instead, which will remove the need for the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor as the compiler-generated ones will be sufficient.

If you then find that copying the data is still a major bottleneck, you could use a `boost::shared_ptr` to hold the string if you can live with the additional level of indirection in normal use. That way, the string will not be copied if the containing object is copied and you still get the safety of RAII.

Comment: It will get rid of the trio entirely, in fact.

Comment: (Kinda repeating myself from a comment from above) Should I be using std::string for file streams? How should I handle an unzip and unrar library that asks for a raw char pointer then?

Also, if I wanted to avoid the copying in the sort(), `boost::shared_ptr` can do that? (I've never used it before.) I read a bit about it. It creates a small pointer-like object that I'll be able to put inside my `Page`s that'll continue to point to the right heap even after the `Page` is moved/sorted?

Comment: `std::string` allows for read access as a C string via the c_str() method. If you're managing an array of chars instead of a string, consider `vector<char>` as mentioned above. `boost::shared_ptr` uses reference counting to determine the lifecycle of the object it points to. The only data that gets copied is what little data shared_ptr uses instead of the whole string so *if* the data copy is a major issue then this approach might improve performance.

Comment: well I know c_str() can convert strings to c strings, but I'm talking about using methods that have `char*` parameters to fill, like `strncpy(char*, const char*, int)` or `fstream.read(char*, int)`. I'm used to creating a `char[size] buffer;` for those methods to "fill". How would I use a `std::string` without using an intermediate char array?

Comment: You don't, but you could use a vector<char>

Comment: I didn't understand how this would help until I looked up & learned about `&vector[0]`. So then, just to make sure, using vectors also means I won't need to use `boost::shared_ptr`/`boost::scoped_array` or a custom swap to avoid deep-copying when sorting, right?

Comment: If you're using a vector<char> as a member in the object, the whole vector will be copied if the object will be copied. It won't be as explicit as calling `memcpy` but the effect will be the same. The reason for using `shared_ptr` in either scenario is that you add a level of indirection to the character array/string and only copy the pointer object to it rather than the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

If using manual char* manipulation isn't part of your criteria for the exercise, you could use std::string and let it handle all the allocation issues for you. The std::swap function used by std::sort is even specialized to call std::string::swap for you, which means that it automatically only swaps the pointers to your string data rather than deep-copying.

If you want to use char* for exercise purposes, probably the easiest way to create a free-standing swap function that takes two Page references and just swaps the internal data pointers around. I believe that as long as sort can see a better match than the standard template, it will call your function instead getting the increased performance.

Finally, to answer your question about the header : Compilers are free to implement headers as actual files that include other headers (even ones that might not normally be expected). Almost certainly your iostream header is including algorithm directly or indirectly. On another compiler your code might fail to compile.

Comment: Funny thing is, when I learned to do this kinda stuff, I learned it in this way *because* they were the exercises I had to do. So the functions that give me the streams I want, like `myFstream.read(buffer, filesize)` want a `char*` for the first parameter. How would I put a `std::string` there instead, without using an intermediate `char*` array?